# Why does JpaRepository while saving entity tried to create entity for null FK key?

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have **Person** table with field ***country*** in it (*FK, can be null*).
When I try to save **Person** with empty ***country*** value, I'll get an error 500 and message

2020-01-30 15:16:37.277  WARN 10524 --- [nio-8098-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2020-01-30 15:16:37.277 ERROR 10524 --- [nio-8098-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ОШИБКА: нулевое значение в столбце "code" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
  Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит (42, null, null, null).
2020-01-30 15:16:37.299 ERROR 10524 --- [nio-8098-exec-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Rough error traduction:

> Error: null value in "code" column breaks NOT NULL restriction Details: The error string contains (42, null, null, null).

```
Person.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_person")
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String patronymic;

    @Column(name = "surname_rus")
    private String surnameRus;

    @Column(name = "name_rus")
    private String nameRus;

    @Column(name = "surname_eng")
    private String surnameEng;

    @Column(name = "name_eng")
    private String nameEng;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    private String settlement;
    private String occupation;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_link",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "link_id", referencedColumnName = "link_id"))
    private List<UrlLink> linkList;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "org_actor",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "org_id", referencedColumnName = "org_id"))
    private List<Org> orgList;

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_hashtag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hashtag_id", referencedColumnName = "hashtag_id"))
    private List<HashTag> hashtagList;


************
Country.java

@Entity
@Table(name="t_country")
@Data

public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
}

create table t_country
(
    country_id serial  not null
        constraint t_country_pkey
            primary key,
    code       char(3) not null
        constraint unique_constr_code
            unique,
    name       text
        constraint unique_constr_name
            unique,
    miscellany text,
    constraint constr_name
        unique (code, name)
);
```

How to save Person entity with empty country?

Comment: Are you sure the country is empty? The error seems to indicate that there is a country with id 42.

Comment: there is no such entity in country table with id 42. I think something tries to create new entity with id 42 and return error with null by the reason code country null.
Added sql in quiestion with t_country creation.

Comment: And when you save the person the country is null? Or do  you instantiate a country with null fields?

Comment: I'm trying to save with 'empty' country, but have 500 error. If I save record in Person table manually evething is ok.

Comment: Is empty country a country with empty fields or is it null? If it is a country with empty fields you have a not null constraint in your country db table definition (not in your java code!). Maybe you had code defined as nullable=false and removed it without changing your db definition?

Answer (score 0):

In your country db table definition the field *code* is defined as

```
code
   char(3) not null
    constraint unique_constr_code
        unique,
```

means that there is a not null constraint on db level.

That's why you can not save a person with a country with empty fields.

So even though you do not have a not null constraint in the java code, the db rejects the value. Maybe you forgot to migrate your db after removing the not null constraint in your java code?